# pass information between client and server using flask

Tags: python, flask

I have client_app.py running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ and server_app.py running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/
each of them has a json object in the program. How could server_app.py send a string to client_app to update its json object?
Could anyone give me an example?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `requests` to send a POST request to the other app.

Somewhere in your app:

```
import requests

def update_other(self, data):
    r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000", data=data)
    ...
```

See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Given there wasn't much information given in the question, would you mind expanding on what you mean by "receive"?

Answer (score 0):

1. From Server to Client you can use [Context Processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templating/#context-processors) or the method suggested by Martin Samson
2. From Client to Server you can use [jquery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/patterns/jquery/) or flask's [url_for](http://codehandbook.org/python-flask-jquery-ajax-post/)